# How to keep the largest value for each row in a list of lists python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of lists as follows

```
array([[9.88945457e-01, 1.12012004e-11, 1.10545428e-02],
       [3.19212970e-03, 9.60482604e-01, 3.63252661e-02],
       [9.97873928e-01, 1.10315885e-12, 2.12607185e-03],
       [5.13391890e-07, 9.84294588e-01, 1.57048982e-02]])
```

I would like to keep the largest value in each row, like so

```
array([[9.88945457e-01],
       [9.60482604e-01],
       [9.97873928e-01],
       [9.84294588e-01]])
```

Does this require a loop to go through each row? Or is this something `enumerate()` or `iterrows()` can handle?

Comment: [`arr.max(axis=1)`](https://uscript.co/public/annoym/python/1e3a96ea.py)

Answer (score 3):

Inseted of looping over the array, vectorizing the operation is much more efficient.

To do so, you have to play with the axis argument of the max function. In this case you should use the axis=1.

```py
import numpy as np


a = np.array([[9.88945457e-01, 1.12012004e-11, 1.10545428e-02],
              [3.19212970e-03, 9.60482604e-01, 3.63252661e-02],
              [9.97873928e-01, 1.10315885e-12, 2.12607185e-03],
              [5.13391890e-07, 9.84294588e-01, 1.57048982e-02]])
print(np.max(a, axis=1))
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is a numpy array

```
myarray.max(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

to find out the largest number you can do it like this:

```
def largest(arr,n): 

# Initialize maximum element 
max = arr[0] 

# Traverse array elements from second 
# and compare every element with  
# current max 
for i in range(1, n): 
    if arr[i] > max: 
        max = arr[i] 
return max


# Driver Code 
arr = [10, 324, 45, 90, 9808] 
n = len(arr) 
Ans = largest(arr,n) 
print ("Largest in given array is",Ans)
```

Comment: This looks like a C answer written in Python.   Plus the tabs are missing.  You are new, but you should look at the help for entering an answer, it will explain how to format your code better.  (Indentation is critical in Python)

Comment: yes you are right this is a c answer in python... but it works ^^ so he just wanted the result i think. And yes off course the indentation in this code is not perfect. The Code of the function needed a "tab" more

Answer (score 1):

Having this array:

```
array = np.array([[9.88945457e-01, 1.12012004e-11, 1.10545428e-02],
       ...        [3.19212970e-03, 9.60482604e-01, 3.63252661e-02],
       ...        [9.97873928e-01, 1.10315885e-12, 2.12607185e-03],
       ...        [5.13391890e-07, 9.84294588e-01, 1.57048982e-02]])
```

If your array it's quite large it's better to use (as suggested by @Guillem or @Muhammad) the max numpy function.

Please note that the max numpy function will return a numpy array

```
np.max(a, axis=1)
>>> array([0.98894546, 0.9604826 , 0.99787393, 0.98429459])
```

However, I think that you can reach the same goal in python using a loop on the array and then use the max() function.

Somthing like this:

```
array = np.array([[9.88945457e-01, 1.12012004e-11, 1.10545428e-02],
      ...        [3.19212970e-03, 9.60482604e-01, 3.63252661e-02],
      ...        [9.97873928e-01, 1.10315885e-12, 2.12607185e-03],
      ...        [5.13391890e-07, 9.84294588e-01, 1.57048982e-02]])

res = []
for sub_list in array:
    max_value = max(sub_list)
    res.append([max_value])
```

This method will return a standard python list

Answer (score 1):

You are using numpy, but in plain python it is simply:

```
maxes = [max(x) for x in numlists]
```

or

```
maxes = list(map(max,numlists))
```

Answer (score 1):

numpy.argmax gets the index of the maximum value of each row
reshape raises one-dimensional data to two-dimensional

```
getArrayMax = lambda array: array[range(array.shape[0]), numpy.argmax(array, axis=1)].reshape(array.shape[0], 1)

>>> getArrayMax(f)
array([[0.98894546],
       [0.9604826 ],
       [0.99787393],
       [0.98429459]])
```

Answer (score 0):

use a list comprehension with a max

```
 arr=np.array([[9.88945457e-01, 1.12012004e-11, 1.10545428e-02],
   [3.19212970e-03, 9.60482604e-01, 3.63252661e-02],
   [9.97873928e-01, 1.10315885e-12, 2.12607185e-03],
   [5.13391890e-07, 9.84294588e-01, 1.57048982e-02]])

 result=[max(item)  for item in arr]
 print(result)
```

output:

```
 [0.988945457, 0.960482604, 0.997873928, 0.984294588]
```